# Magento1.9 : Update order status flow for virtual products

Tags: magento-1.9, order-status

I have a magento store where all products are virtual type, currently all order's initial status is **pending** and after payment success order status updated to **complete** (as invoice created with paid status).

I want to update this flow as following :

1) When order place (before redirecting to payment gateway) order status should be **pending**,

2) after payment success (redirecting back to store from payment gateway) order status should be **processing**,

3) and from admin I have added a custom button in order view page, so on click on it order status should be **complete**

How can I manage this flow in my case?

Comment: Can you please explain the business requirement? What is the problem with complete status after placing the order

Comment: Actually I'm making live ticket booking of third party after payment success and if live booking success only then want to complete order status.